# Adding an additional GET variable on form submit

Tags: javascript, php

I have two "forms" that consist of a single dropdown list each. I'm submitting both forms with javascript `onchange="this.form.submit()"` I need to reserve a variable, if it is set, on the second form submit. I have the form submitting to the same page and currently, it isn't passing the first variable.

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>" method="GET">
    <select name="show" style="width:100%;" onchange="this.form.submit()">
        <option value="cond" <?php if(isset($_GET['show'])&&$_GET['show']=='cond'||!isset($_GET['show'])) { echo 'selected'; } ?>>Condensed</option>
        <option value="full" <?php if(isset($_GET['show'])&&$_GET['show']=='full') { echo 'selected'; } ?>>Show All</option>
    </select>
</form>


<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>" method="GET">
    <select name="sort_slsp" style="width:100%;" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <option value="">--Choose Salesperson--</option>
            <?php
                $get_all_slsp = mysqli_query($lmcon, "SELECT * FROM slsps ORDER BY slsp_name");
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($get_all_slsp)) {
                    echo '<option value="' . $row['slsp_id'] . '">' . $row['slsp_name'] . '</option>';
                }
            ?>
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: please show some of your code...

Comment: I added the two forms above.

Comment: I don't understand. Where is the variable on second form? If you want submit an additional value with the form, you can add (after `<form>` declaration, before `<select>` tag) something like `<input type="hidden" name="myVariable" value="<?php echo $myVariableValue; ?>">`. But 
I do not know if I understand the question.

Comment: @fusion3k: I think the value is contained in `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]`, from the first form submit, and since OP uses it as value of the `action` attribute, they expect it to be send with the rest of the form. (Why that doesn’t happen – see my answer.) A hidden field is the (easiest) way to go here, that’s right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**When the form `method` is `GET`, browsers overwrite any possibly existing query string part of the URL specified via the `action` attribute with the *new* query string they construct from the form fields.**

The easiest solution here is to add that additional value you want to submit as a hidden input field into the form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="foo" value="bar">
```

Seing as your first `select` field has the name `show`, and that is likely the value you want to pass on here(?), you’d fill that value attribute as such,

```
value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['show']); ?>"
```

(Adding a check for whether that parameter exists in the first place, and maybe output a default value if not, I’ll leave up to you.)

Comment: I was gonna suggest him to make the form's action URL contain already present URL query, but your solution is more interesting for sure.

Comment: @Nino: _“to make the form's action URL contain already present URL query”_ – that’s what they already had (if I understood OP correctly), but it doesn’t work (see first paragraph of my answer.)

Comment: No, I meant have a form action like this `?foo=bar&` instead of current URL.

Comment: @Nino Yes, I know. That does not work – again, first paragraph of my answer …

Comment: Really? Okay, weird.

Comment: YES! :) I'm now checking if the variable is set (on each form) and if so, adding the hidden input. Super simple! Thanks a ton man!

Comment: Is it appropriate protocol around here to edit my question with the solution, above?

Comment: @jds: No, you can leave the question as it is. Upvoting and/or marking an answer as accepted is the mechanism here to tell people that an answer helped you solve your problem. (If you’re new here, I suggest a quick look at the tour, to understand how SO works a little better: http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Thanks brother. I appreciate it. You've been a big help! Before I look, is it against the rules to hire a person for consultation through here?

Comment: Offering a job inside a question here would get it closed quite quickly, and http://stackoverflow.com/jobs is for “bigger” jobs. For smaller consultancy work (business or private), I suggest you look/search locally if possible.